# Delphi translation project EResNotFound

Tags: delphi, translation

I am working on the development of a large management application that I am translating with the tools provided with Delphi (language DLL).

When I run the translated version, I have an `EResNotFound` exception when I want to run my reports.

Some components of the report generator used in the application are inherited from a `TForm`. And the DFM of the components are not recovered by the translation tool.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the report generator and the editor has still not responded to my support request.

How can we get around this problem? Has anyone ever faced this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.